# Data Analyzing-Stream Processing (Storm) and Complex Event Processing

Tags: apache-storm, complex-event-processing, esper, siddhi, stream-processing

I m doing some research on stream processing combined with complex event processing.I want to use an open source software to work on Apache's Storm.I have found CEP engines like Esper,Siddhi,Sase+ but i am looking for something to work specifically on Apache-Storm.Is there any CEP engine which adjusts perfectly on Storm and if so whats the inner architecture of the engine (working for example in 1 bolt or something else).Any information is most welcome.

Comment: Storm-Esper bolts can be found at https://github.com/miguelantonio/storm-esper-bolt and https://github.com/tomdz/storm-esper

Answer (score 1):

[WSO2 CEP](http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/) uses Siddhi as its core CEP engine, it's strongly integrated with Apache Storm, and it also supports distributed deployment of Siddhi query plan by adding distribution annotations to it. The documentation and samples are available [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Creating+a+Storm+Based+Distributed+Execution+Plan).